# How can LEDs sense darkness?

Tags: arduino, led

I've read in the *Make* magazine that LEDs can sense darkness. How should I use it in a breadboard circuit?
Is it possible to read the ambient light level and send it to the computer?
How does this work? Does that mean a speaker can be a microphone? In that case, how would you do that?

Comment: Yes, a speaker can be turned into a microphone. Google has lots to say on the subject so I won't elaborate. I haven't heard about the LED detecting darkness before so I'm going to check that out.

Comment: All P-N junctions are sensitive to light. Some are simply less sensitive than others.

Comment: Ah, your question is misleading OP. I read the article and the LED doesn't detect darkness, a phototransistor does and turns on an LED. That makes more sense.

Comment: @I.Wolfe: It is actually possible to [use a LED to detect light](http://www.instructables.com/id/LEDs-as-light-sensors/). It's just not a very *good* detector.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Ah ok yeah that makes sense. Thanks for explaining, my brain is slow on Fridays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A led acts a light detecting diode as well i.e you can sense the extent of darkness and brightness by a LED but it is not going to be as effective as the one's made for this purpose specifically.

http://www.instructables.com/id/LEDs-as-light-sensors/

You can make it on your own and this instructable will prove to be helpful.

And answering your second question, yes the speaker can also act as a microphone based on this concept only.

Answer (score 1):

Taking this question literally, I don't think you can sense complete visual darkness with an LED. A human eye can respond to [less than 100 photons](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/see_a_photon.html), so I think you'd need something like a photomultiplier tube, silicon photomultiplier or (maybe) a cooled avalanche photodiode to detect the presence of total darkness.

Sensing normal room ambient light levels is very easily done with a dedicated chip such as those [from Taos](http://datasheet.octopart.com/TSL2550D-TAOS-datasheet-578390.pdf) (née Texas Instruments) which give you a digital output and has built-in filtering to knock out mains frequency-related brightness variations.

[image]